# Community wiki posts don't show change in username

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, answers, community-wiki, user-interface

A while ago, I had answered this question with community wiki: [Alternative of if-else and switch statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22953136/alternative-of-if-else-and-switch-statements/22953248#22953248)

At that time, I had temporarily used a different username for the fun of it, but changed it back a while after.

However, on the post, it still shows the user who posted it as "OneKitten", not my current username:

> [image: community wiki, 3 revs, OneKitten]

Is this a bug?

Comment: I think this is probably [meta-tag:status-bydesign] as it's always done this.

Comment: Does it change if you edit the post?

Comment: @ChrisF: there we go, that makes sense.

Comment: The CW notice is "baked" during post save, so re-edits will update it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "flair" for CW answers only updates when the post is edited.

To get the name to change you'll have to edit the post, so that it's re-rendered.