# How to find community wiki posts?

Tags: support, community-wiki

I'm trying to find community wiki posts, but when I search for them I get many results that are not community wiki posts. For example [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266663/community-wiki-posts-dont-show-change-in-username).

Even this question itself will show up for such a search.

`wiki:yes` is a good start, especially combined with `is:q`, e.g.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=wiki%3Ayes+is%3Aq  - but even in this example, I only get 13 results. There must be a lot more, so where are the community wiki pages and how can I find them?

Comment: As far as CW here on meta goes, you're pretty much only going to see that on questions which are also a FAQ. Only a moderator can make a question community wiki, and we rarely would ever have a reason to do so on a non-FAQ question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CW on child meta's doesn't really make sense as there's no reputation to be gained and lost here. The only reason would be to lower the threshold for community editing and most people don't think of that.

I think that there really are only 13 questions marked community wiki here on MSO.

Comment: I've recently gained the badge that allows to edit CW, but I don't know how to find them nor how to identify one. This info should be more accesible (moderators, take note)

Comment: Same here. I still don't know where to find CW posts.