# Community wiki attribution should take into account name changes

Tags: feature-request, community-wiki

I've stumbled upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29847/get-last-item-in-a-table-sql). It's a community wiki question, and displays 'KiwiBastard' as one of the contributors:

[image]

However, clicking the link to their profile, it turns out their username has changed:

[image]

I would have expected attribution to display the user's current user name, not the user name they had at the time they wrote the post.

This has been raised [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266663/community-wiki-posts-dont-show-change-in-username) before - but was marked as [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

This is a request to change that behaviour, as there are cases where a user has changed their username, and may not appreciate attribution/representation of their old username.

Comment: You'll no doubt have to give a *lot* more examples of where it says something like "hitler" before they'll ever consider doing that work.

Comment: @HansPassant Perhaps. However, my point is more focused on providing 'correct' attribution by addressing users as they prefer to be addressed. There are cases on this site where people have changed their real-life names and have updated their Stack Exchange profiles to reflect that, for a variety of reasons. I don't think this should revolve around *why* their username changed, but whether or not we should provide attribution to their new username.

Comment: @HansPassant What makes you think it's that much work? They have the user ID there, looking up the actual name shouldn't be that hard. It would probably take me an hour or so to fix this using a userscript (yes, without testing, and in a bad way), but it shouldn't take days of development time for them. In my opinion, proper attribution is important on Stack Overflow, and it's something they should consider doing, even if it isn't a major issue. It's not urgent of course, so you risk _status: 6-to-8-weeks_.

Comment: It would be useful if names in comments caught up too, especially those with @ tags, but also those without.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler don't get me started on the tagging "system"... :(

Answer (score 11):

This is *definitely* caching, telling by this row in the SEDE:

[image: OwnerDisplayName]

The problem here seems to be that the cache is updated when an edit is made, instead of on a cron job or whatever.

There *aren't* many community wiki posts, so it probably wouldn't be too much to ask for a task that updates this every so often.