# Pings in comments don't change when the pinged user changes username

Tags: bug, comment-replies, display-names

Example: [Error while executing os.getcwd()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23889636) - from context, it's clear that the answerer pinged the OP in the comment discussion under the answer, but the name in the ping doesn't match OP's current username.

This could potentially be an issue for people who change their username for privacy reasons (previously posted under a real name but no longer wish to expose that information), because of a legal name change, because of a gender transition (they are now "deadnamed" by the system), etc. (I feel bad about linking an example, because I don't know if one or more of these applies to the specific case; but I don't really see how else to demonstrate the issue without abusing the system and doing quite a bit of additional work.)

I assume this is related to [Community wiki posts don't show change in username](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266663), but it isn't feasible to edit all these comments to re-render them, if that would even work. At least, as a concerned curator who observes such an issue, I cannot edit the comment although I would be able to edit a CW answer.

Comment: Same question on [meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31851/change-all-username-references-in-comments-when-a-user-changes-their-name). It is status-declined

Comment: "*This could potentially be an issue for people who change their username for privacy reasons*" more discussion on [Users need to be able to remove themselves and all their data from the site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336000/241919)

Comment: The only way out would be comment deletion. You could flag them of course, but ain't nobody got time to flag all comments for that reason. If it really is such an issue then maybe comments should auto-delete after a given timeperiod. Weeks, months, as long as they don't linger forever.

Comment: That's like saying the only way out is suicide, @Gimby. Not very helpful. Deleting comments that were 100% valid when written, but you've since changed your user name, is tantamount to vandalism. I've stopped users from doing it before, and I would do so again in the future.

Comment: @CodyGray Wait, you stopped users from deleting their own comments? That's possible? There's a comment undeletion mechanism?

Comment: Yes, that's possible. Comments can be undeleted. And users can be stopped from doing it by suspending them. Vandalism of content posted to this site is not allowed; that goes for questions, answers, and comments. (To be clear, there *are* valid cases for deleting comments, but mass-deletion of all comments for some reason unrelated to content is vandalism.)